# Tumblr variables in jquery script

Tags: jquery, variables, themes, tumblr

I am trying to make my own custom theme for Tumblr (actually trying to create some kind of a portfolio with a blog on it's base) and have faced a problem:

I am using jQuery and want to insert Tumblr variables into that script to be able to change colors from the Appearance panel on Tumblr site. But it doesn't seem to work. Maybe there is something special about syntax that I don't consider. Here's the script with inserted variables.

```
<script>
    $("#Home").hover(
        function(over){
            $("#Home").css('background-color','{color:Home-hover}');
            $("#title").css('color','{color:Home-hover}');
        },
        function(out){
            $("#Home").css('background-color','{color:Buttons}');
            $("#title").css('color','{color:Buttons}');
        }
    );
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you place `{color:buttons}` in single quotes, you're putting exactly those characters into the CSS. Did you want to access the value stored in an object on the page?  Maybe there's a `color` object that has a key `Buttons`, which you could pass to jQuery's css handler like:

```
$("#title").css('color',document.color.Buttons)
```

or:

```
 $("#title").css('color',document.color["Buttons"])
```

That is, assuming those Tumblr variables exist in the document global scope. If they are created inside a closure like `(function() { ... })`, then you won't be able to access them outside the closure.

## Edit

The true power of jQuery is that you can access and manipulate just about everything on the page, including meta data.  Play around with [my jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vAkDQ/8/).  The basic idea is to store your `{color:Buttons}` variable in a javascript variable and then set your css based on that.

### Inside `$(document).ready()`

```
$("#Home").on("mouseenter", function() {
   var metaColorButtons = $("meta[name='color:Buttons']").prop("content");
   $("#title").css('color', metaColorButtons);
 });

$("#Home").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("#title").css('color', '#000');
});
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am kind of noob in web development and maybe a bit stupid with my questions and explenations but please bare with me. My aim was to make my title change color along with the button of menu when I hover a button. I found the way to do it only with CSS but then I had to put both elements into same DIV which seems impossible to me. So I decided to use jQuery (actually the first time I am using it). I am trying to feed jQuery a Tumblr variables which are {color:Buttons}, {color:...} and so on. These variables are fed into css also.

Comment: No problem. Can you show us an example of the kind of variable you're trying to access on Tumblr?

Comment: Well, here is my whole code so far. Maybe from here you will understand better what I need and how to achieve that. Thank you for your help.   [LINK](http://pastie.org/private/9zfcght4kwr3lftcfno9qa)

Comment: I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance very much. Here is the link one more time - [LINK](http://pastie.org/private/9zfcght4kwr3lftcfno9qa)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Saw it after posting my message. It seems helpful, I just need learn the basics of JS to start understanding the principles of how it works. Will try playing with your example and figure out. By the way maybe you could suggest some alternative way of achieving same effect with only CSS? JavaScript seems like too much for me now. I will definitely spend time learning its basics but now I lack time. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: @Dima You need to use CSS with transitions.

Comment: Hellow, Austin. I still can't get the script to work. It seems that JavaScript won't catch the Tumblr variable. I made a little test here's the link. Could you please look and help me. [HERE IS THE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej2ep/27/)

Comment: You can't change the original css style block with javascript.  What's happening is the element's style attribute is being changed on the fly. This overrides anything in the <style> tag block.  Therefore, what you're asking for in the fiddle doesn't really make sense. However, jQuery should be able to get the value from the <meta> tag in the page's <head>, which is what I did in my fiddle. If that's not the case, then I don't know how to fix your issue.

Comment: Well, anyway, thank you. I will be trying to figure it out. Have a good day.